# minted NFT is shown as solid color of picture in Nami wallet

Tags: nft, nami-wallet, utxo, mint

I have some questions about NFT mint.
I minted NFT using Nami Wallet API, but sometimes error occurred.

1. I need to mint several NFTs at once. So I submit minting transactions in for loop.
   But sometimes transactions make Utxo failure error. I think it's because the new transaction's Utxo input is not same as the old transacion's Utxo input. Help me to mint several NFTs at once.
2. And sometimes Minted NFT is shown as solid color picture in Nami wallet.
   I checked that image in IPFS and it same as what I uploaded. But why Nami wallet can't include it?

[image: Nami wallet shows solid color picture instead of uploaded picture]

Answer (score 0):

Try to have the `asset_name` and `name` the same:

```
"asset_name": "TestNFT1",
"name": "TestNFT1",
```

For some reason, when they are different, Nami shows the solid color, in ccvault/Eternl works well with spaces.